# QML : Cannot assign to non-existent property

Tags: qt, qml

I am using QT 5.12. Getting this error, what i have missed.
I am able to detect (able to **click** on this object **checkEngine** in QT creator) checkEngine in my main.qml.
I am able to build but when I try to run it gives me this error. :--

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/src_qml/main.qml:17:9: Cannot assign to non-existent property "checkEngine" qrc:/src_qml/main.qml: 17
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "black"
    title: qsTr("Warning Indicator TelTail")
    id : window_id

    Rectangle
    {
        id: cluster

        checkEngine{
            id: cheakEngineID
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

}
```

checkEngine.qml :--

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {
    width: 131
    height: 106

    Image
    {
        id: root
        source: "/images/Check-Engine-Light_1.png"
        x : 0
        y : 0
    }
}
```

QRC file :---

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>src_qml/main.qml</file>
        <file>images/Check-Engine-Light.png</file>
        <file>images/Check-Engine-Light_1.png</file>
        <file>images/Teltail_base.png</file>
        <file>src_qml/checkEngine.qml</file>
        <file>src_qml/telTailBase.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/files"/>
    <qresource prefix="/src"/>
    <qresource prefix="/src_qml"/>
</RCC>
```

main.cpp :--

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();
    for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
        const QString baseName = "Cluster_application_" + QLocale(locale).name();
        if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
            app.installTranslator(&translator);
            break;
        }
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/src_qml/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is project view :--
[image]

Comment: Please check [Naming Custom QML Object Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#naming-custom-qml-object-types) document, especially this line: _It must begin with an uppercase letter_

Comment: Yes this resolved the issue.. thanks.

Comment: Renaming file from checkEngine.qml to CheckEngine.qml .. worked... first letter should be capital letter...